# download large file and large zip file after socket timeout exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, https

Currently I am trying to download a large file and download a ZIP file after adding xls files in it, but when the ZIP file is large due to socket timeout exception ZIP file is corrupted, and one single file is also terminating unexpectedly. What is the best way to solve this problem?

I think I should write a thread which runs asynchronously and do the download process, is this the correct approach?

Please suggest a correct approach.

Comment: can you just increase your timeout limit?

Comment: Actually global timeut is 1 min, so I could not increase time out limit in my application.

Comment: so the question is where you are downloading the zip file? is it frontend or in your backend application?

Comment: I am downloading file from frontend, which is angular js application.

Comment: var zip = new JSZip();
var count = 0;
var zipFilename= "zipFilename.zip";
var urls = [
  'http://image-url-1',
  'http://image-url-2',
  'http://image-url-3'
];
urls.forEach(function(url){
  var filename = "filename";
  // loading a file and add it in a zip file
  JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
     if(err) {
        throw err; // or handle the error
     }  zip.file(filename, data, {binary:true});
     count++;
     if (count == urls.length) {
       var zipFile = zip.generate({type: "blob"});
       saveAs(zipFile, zipFilename);
     }
  });
});"

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jszip.min.js" type="text/javascript">  </script>

Comment: https://gist.github.com/noelvo/4502eea719f83270c8e9